# R: ggplot and the use of colors to fill gaps

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a time series data with gaps.
I have used multiple imputation packages to fill the gaps.

Through ggplot, I have generated both of the plots.
I would like to use a different color for the modified section of the plot for better visualization.

Original plot with gaps

```
ggplot(data = df_final, mapping = aes(x = day_of_year, y = bookings)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Plot with gaps filled

```
ggplot(data = df_result, mapping = aes(x = day_of_year, y = bookings_imputed)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

`df_final` & `df_result` are the dataframes used for original & gap filled plots respectively.

Comment: Create a new variable that indicates whether an observation was imputed and then map colour to this variable. Consider to share a reproducible example if you face problems.

Comment: Agree. Could do a `dplyr` `mutate(case_when())` to create the new column.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] -Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
require(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(imputedValues = imputeTS::na.random(values), 
         type = ifelse(is.na(values) == TRUE, "impute", "real")) %>% 
  gather(var, val, -time, -type) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, val, group = var, color = var)) + 
  geom_line()
```

Output: 
[image]

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(time = 1:10, 
                 values = rep(c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest would be to draw imputed line first and then original one on the same plot with different color.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df_result, 
            mapping = aes(x = day_of_year, y = bookings_imputed),
            color = 'red')
  geom_line(data = df_final,
            mapping = aes(x = day_of_year, y = bookings),
            color = 'black')
```

Comment: It isn't really good `ggplot2` practice to make multiple geoms that serve essentially the same purpose. You're generally much better off working with long-shaped data and mapping a variable (such as something marking data as observed vs imputed) to an aesthetic like color

Comment: Agree, but as it requires additional data wrangling I decided to give the most straight forward (doesn't mean the best) answer.